# URL points to different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello Everoyone when i go to `/categories` it points to `UsersController#show`.

**It should be going to `CategoriesController#index`**

Here is a glimps of my routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get ':id' => 'users#show', as: :user_profile

  resources :users, path: ':username' do
    collection do
      resources :outfits 
      resources :cart_items, only: [:create, :index, :destroy]
      resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
      resources :addresses, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      resources :paypals, except: [:index]
    end
  end

  resources :categories
end
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of your first route :

```
get ':id' => 'users#show', as: :user_profile
```

This is taking **any** single slash and text path and sending it to `users#show`. So in the case of categories it is entering the string 'categories' into the :id, parameter and going to your users show method. I suspect you will find the same result with any resources paths you have placed outside your `resources :users` block.

I would suggest keeping your routes simple and using

```
resources :users, only: :show
```

or, if you really want to use that route, i would stick it at the bottom of your routes file so that other resources get checked first, and it is the last processed